# Pass Object of type `Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest` from jquery to Mvc Action

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**Objective:**
I want to pass an object of type `Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest` to the Mvc action, so that i can get the results from database according to the sorting and filtering applied.

**Problem/Obstacle:**
The object gets null when it reaches to the action.

**MY Controller Action**

```
    public ActionResult Getresults([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, Int32 TotalRec)
    {
        try
        {
            //get data from DAL
            var result = new DataSourceResult()
            {
                Data = List, // Process data (paging and sorting applied)
                Total = TotalRec
            };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

**My jquery Function**

```
function getData() {
    var gridDatasource = $('#gridname').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.options;
    var datatoPost = "{'request': '" + JSON.stringify(new kendo.data.DataSource(gridDatasource)) + "', 'TotalRec': '" + 100 + "'}";
    //new kendo.data.DataSource
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '/Administrator/Getresults/',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: datatoPost,
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: false,
        success: function (value) {
            alert(value.d);
        },
        error: function () { alert("Ajax Error"); }
    });
}
```

I tried to JSON.stringify but still the same
and also like `var datatoPost = "{'request': '" + JSON.stringify(gridDatasource) + "', 'TotalRec': '" + 100 + "'}";`

Do i need to parse my object here or may be convert its type.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but KendoUI wrappers are really helpful, as they render the required javascript on to the page. You should use these wrapper libraries. Check the demos in this [link](http://www.kendoui.com/server-wrappers.aspx)

Comment: I am also facing similar problem.

Comment: For the record, solution provided by @spottedone works like a charm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me worked the following:

```
$("#excel").kendoButton({
  click: function (event) {

    var data = grid.dataSource._params();
    var prepared = grid.dataSource.transport.parameterMap(data);

    $.post("/Root/AnotherControllerMethod", prepared, 
       function (data, status, xhr) {
         console.log("Ok!");
       }
    );
  }
});
```