# Kendo UI MVC Grid DataSourceRequest JavaScript Post Additional Data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to create a click event for an button that is not part of the Kendo UI Grid controls.

This was fairly easily accomplished with this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20973015/60629

**Working DataSourceRequest Code**:

JavaScript

```
$("#excel").kendoButton({
  click: function (event) {
    var grid = $('#grid_patients').data('kendoGrid');
        var parameterMap = grid.dataSource.transport.parameterMap;
        var sortData = grid.dataSource.sort();
        var filterData = grid.dataSource.filter();
        var groupData = grid.dataSource.group();
        var prepared = parameterMap({ sort: sortData, filter: filterData, group: groupData });

    $.post("/Root/Getresults", prepared, 
       function (data, status, xhr) {
         console.log("Ok!");
       }
    );
  }
});
```

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Getresults([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    ...
```

**Additional Data**

However, I need to also pass additional parameters. 
JavaScript Changes

```
 var extraParams = { /* appended data object */
     request: prepared,
     additionaldata: "test"
 };
 $.post("/Root/Getresults", extraParams, 
  ...
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Getresults([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string additionaldata)
{
    ...
```

The original returns the DataSourceRequest with data and the secondary one will return the additionaldata, but has an empty request object.

I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: How did you bind grid_patients at initial page load?

Comment: It's an .NET MVC loading. I've actually figured this problem out now.. and feeling slightly moronic because of how long it took me. I didn't figure it out alone either.. a coworker with more Kendo under his belt did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a coworker the answer became fairly obvious! The mistake was in how I setup the JSON object being sent, the request parameter shouldn't be used.

```
var extraParams = { /* appended data object */
     sort: prepared.sort,
     filter: prepared.filter,
     group: prepared.group,
     additionaldata: "test"
 };
```

DataSourceRequest properties are automatically synced up to the parameter in the controller.